# OSX - Cocoa - Exception when closing a sheet

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I am playing with using a sheet in my app.

I have a little test project setup to find my way.

I did have this code working:

```
- (IBAction)activateSheet:(id)sender {
    if (!_sheet)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Sheet" owner:self];
    [NSApp beginSheet:self.sheet
       modalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:NULL
          contextInfo:NULL];
}
```

but the loadNibNamed method is deprecated.

So I substitute this:

```
- (IBAction)activateSheet:(id)sender {
    if (!_sheet)
        NSLog(@"1");
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Sheet" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    [NSApp beginSheet:self.sheet
       modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:NULL
          contextInfo:NULL];
}
```

The sheet opens fine. But if I press save or cancel, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

UPDATE - This is a breeze with 10.9:

```
- (IBAction)activateSheet:(id)sender {
    if (!_sheet)
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Sheet" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    [[[NSApp delegate] window] beginSheet:self.sheet completionHandler:nil];    
}



- (void)endSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow returnCode:(NSModalResponse)returnCode {
    [sheetWindow orderOut:self];    
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self doSave];
    result = 1;
    [self endSheet:self.sheet returnCode:result];   
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    result = 0;
    [self endSheet:self.sheet returnCode:result];   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

implement like below:-

```
 [NSApp beginSheet:self.sheet
       modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:@selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
          contextInfo:nil];

    - (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
if (returnCode == NSAlertDefaultReturn)
{
        [sheet orderOut:self];

    }

else if (returnCode == NSAlertAlternateReturn)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain.. I just read the docs, I realized it was the endSheet method (now also deprecated) and was trying to figure out the syntax. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hussain, could you please be a bit more specific - I'm getting an undeclared identifier on "didEndSheet". Thanks again.

Comment: i think I'm missing the point.. I have this: - (IBAction)activateSheet:(id)sender {
    if (!_sheet)
  NSLog(@"1");
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Sheet" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
 [NSApp beginSheet:self.sheet
       modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:)
          contextInfo:nil];

}

- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{

Comment: Hussain, I'm sure I checked that but apparently not.. That works perfectly.. But one more question... I don't crash, but how do I target, say Cancel or OK buttons?

Comment: ok, but (and I appreciate very much the help).. how does the didEndSheet method intercept the cancel or ok buttons. Right now, the buttons go to their respective method, so didEndSheet isn't getting called..

Comment: Sorry again didEndSheet in this method only you can check which button has pressed.

Comment: Ok great so i have updated the code accordingly. Please follow

Comment: Inside didEndSheet method you will get return code on the basis of button click it will return button value accordingly.