# How do I open an NSSheet in Mavericks?

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller, osx-mavericks

In Mavericks, the methods to open and close NSSheets has changed. And to make it tougher, the [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000741-CH2-SW7) do not match the current documentation (see below).

I'm trying to do this:

MainSheetController (NSWindowController):

```
-(IBAction)callSheet:(id)sender {
    [sheetController openSheet];
}
```

SheetController (NSObject):

```
 (void)openSheet {  
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:sheetName owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    NSLog(@"1");
    [self.mainWindowController.window beginSheet:self.sheet completionHandler:nil];
    NSLog(@"2");    
}
```

I get to 2, with no errors or warnings, but no sheet..

Current Documentation:

```
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow completionHandler:(void (^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);
- (void)beginCriticalSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow completionHandler:(void (^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);
#endif
```

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561754/osx-cocoa-exception-when-closing-a-sheet/19562056#19562056

Comment: @hussainShabbir That answer is incorrect from Mavericks onwards, as the `[NSApp beginSheet:...]` method is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Hope it's ok to post..

MainWindow.h

```
@interface MainWindowController : NSWindowController {
    NSString *sheetName;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *sheet;
    id result1;
    id result2;
    ...
    id resultn;
}

@property (strong) NSString *sheetName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSWindow *sheet;

-(IBAction)callSheet0:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)callSheet1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)callSheetn:(id)sender;

- (void)openSheet;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
```

MainWindow.m

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [super windowDidLoad];
    sheetName = [[NSString alloc] init];
}


-(IBAction)callSheet0:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    sheetName = @"Sheet0";
    [self openSheet];
}
....

-(IBAction)callSheetn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    sheetName = @"Sheetn";
    [self openSheet];


- (void)openSheet {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"sheetName: %@",sheetName );
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:sheetName owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    [self.window beginSheet:self.sheet completionHandler:nil];

}

- (void)save:(NSButton*)sender {

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 0:
            [self doSave1];
            result = @"1";
            break;

        case 1:
            [self doSave2];
            result = @"2";
            break;

        case n:
            [self doSaven];
            result = @"x";
            break;
    }
    [self endSheet:self.sheet returnCode:result];
}


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    result = @"0";
    [self endSheet:self.sheet returnCode:result];
    // returnCode is optional
}

//endSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow  {
- (void)endSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow returnCode:returnCode {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [sheetWindow orderOut:self];

}

- (void)save:(NSButton*)sender {

    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 0:
            [self doSave1];
            result = @"1";
            break;

            case n:
            [self doSave3];
            result = @"3";
            break;
    }
    [self endSheet:self.sheet returnCode:result];
}
```

With this method, new in 10.9,I don't need a special sheet controller, and control remains quote local.

Comment: What does that indicate for the completionHandler?

Comment: I used a switch instead of a completion handler. YMMV.

Answer (score 11):

```
- (IBAction)userButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    UserLoginWindowController * wc = [UserLoginWindowController new];
    // we keep a reference, so the WC doesn't deallocate
    self.modalWindowController = wc;

    [[self window] beginSheet:[wc window] completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        self.modalWindowController = nil;
    }];

}
```

in the UserLoginWindowController

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [[[self window] sheetParent] endSheet:[self window] returnCode:NSModalResponseCancel];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
- (IBAction)showSheet:(id)sender
{
    if (_windowController == nil)
    {
        _windowController = [MyWindowController new];
    }

    [[self window] beginSheet:[_windowController window] completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode)
    {
    }];
}

// And inside your MyWindowController class:

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowNibName"]; // TODO: Change the name of your NIB
    return self;
}
```

In your nib file, make sure the "Visible At Launch" flag is unticked for the window.

Comment: This is not working for me, in MyWindowController `initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window` is being called with a `nil` `window` parameter and sheet is not showing.

Comment: The "Visible At Launch" flag got me. +1

Comment: Also, if you notice your sheet is not appearing, ensure that you link the controller's window property to the actual window in IB.